# Java RMI: Server and Client work well in the same folder, Not work when in different folders in the same PC?

Tags: java, rmi

I am new to RMI

I tried this [example](http://www.java2all.com/1/5/22/114/Technology/RMI/RMI-Program/RMI-example). This works as expected.

Calculator.class
CalculatorImpl.class + CalculatorImpl_Stub.class
CalculatorServer.class
+
CalculatorClient.class

Actually I am planning to test it in two different PCs. But instead of that, I started trying it in the same PC in **two** different folders.

**One folder conatins the Server:**
Calculator.class *:interface*
CalculatorImpl.class + CalculatorImpl_Stub.class
CalculatorServer.class

**The other folder contains the Client:**
Calculator.class  *:this is just a copy of the Calculator interface of the Server above*
CalculatorClient.class

When I try to run things
The server is running well

Now when I run the client this error printed:

```
java.rmi.UnmarshalException: error unmarshalling return; nested exception is:
        java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub (no security manag
er: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.Naming.lookup(Unknown Source)
        at CalculatorClient.main(CalculatorClient.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: CalculatorImpl_Stub (no security ma
nager: RMI class loader disabled)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.LoaderHandler.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader$2.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.rmi.server.RMIClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.MarshalInputStream.resolveClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
        at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
        ... 3 more
```

- They work well in the same folder.
- error when they are in two different folders.

Why?
How to work around this error?

Comment: Did you get that when exporting? When binding? When looking up?

Comment: @EJP I get it when running the client class. I have no info other than the exception I posted.

Comment: On the contrary. You have an entire stack trace, of which you only posted the top two lines. If you have posted it all I wouldn't have had to ask that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class named in the exception isn't available on the clients CLASSPATH. So fix that. The remote stub and interface and everything they depend on must be distributed to the client.

Comment: I updated the error message: I changed the `catch` clause from `System.out.println("Exception is : "+e);` to  `e.printStackTrace();`. In this answer do you mean I need to copy the stub and interface files into the client folder (I alredy copied the interface, I will try copying the stub folder).

Comment: Thank you, I copied the interface, and the  stub files into the client folder, and works well.

Answer (score 1):

You primary problem is following an RMI example which is *very out of date*.  here's a hint, if the RMI example includes the use of `rmic` (or stubs and skeletons), don't use it.  I would suggest starting from the [sun/oracle tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

The most common reason of this problem is calling the `UnicastRemoteObject`.[exportObject(Remote obj)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/rmi/server/UnicastRemoteObject.html). From the documentation you will see it returns an instance of `RemoteStub` so that stub class must be available, this is only possible if you have generated with `rmic`.

Use `UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(Remote obj, int port)` instead. It returns an interface (`Remote`) and would work without generated classes with recent releases.